# Java PayPal Client Side Express Checkout using REST(redirect_urls not working)

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

```
   Client Side Express Checkout using REST to integrate PayPal in java to do transaction by PayPal account or by using credit/debit cards.
```

What I want paypal to **redirect on my java controller** after successful payment so that I can save the payment details on server.

Code to make a REST API calls in jsp page

```
<script>
    paypal.Button.render({
                        env : 'production',
                        client : {
                            sandbox : 'YYY',
                            production : 'XXX'
                        },
                        commit : true,
                        payment : function(data, actions) {
                            return actions.payment.create({
                                payment : {
                                    transactions : [ {
                                        amount : {
                                            total : 1.2,
                                            currency : 'JPY'
                                        } 
                                    } ],
                                    redirect_urls: {
                                        return_url : "http://localhost:8080/tpoint-jaxrs/web/success_redirection",
                                        cancel_url : "http://localhost:8080/tpoint-jaxrs/web/cancel_redirection"                                    
                                      }
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        onCancel : function(data, actions) {
                        },
                        onAuthorize : function(data, actions) {
                        return actions.payment.execute().then(
                                            function(payment) {

                                            });
                        }

                    }, '#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

But after **success/cancel** of paypal payment, paypal is not calling supplied **java controller urls**.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost has to be replaced with your website hostname, otherwise PayPal tries to open it's own server.